# How to get QGIS to start up?

Tags: qgis, mac

I'm having a crash on startup that appears to've come from nowhere—I'd not used QGIS in a while and then tried to launch it and it crashed. This happened on both my work and home computers, so I suspect it's related to a system update (running MacOS 10.12.4); QGIS 2.18.2/2.14.3 (depending on computer) installed from KyngChaos along with python lib.

Here's the crash report I'm getting:

```
Process:               QGIS [1403]
Path:                  /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/QGIS
Identifier:            org.qgis.qgis2
Version:               2.18.2 (2.18.2 [exported])
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           QGIS [1403]
User ID:               502

Date/Time:             2017-04-24 11:01:35.517 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.4 (16E195)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        CE6880BA-8529-B952-7BBC-A72CAED27607


Time Awake Since Boot: 540 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

Application Specific Information:
dyld: in dlopen()
BUG IN LIBTRACE: MH not found
```

What's going on here? How can I get QGIS to launch?

Comment: I don't know much about MacOS, but I suspect that a system update destroyed your QGIS installation`s dependencies. Can you re-install QGIS?

Comment: I can confirm a similar issue and it is related to the 10.12.4 update. A reinstall has NOT fixed it for me.

Comment: I have the same issues already for a month. It is said on KingChaos, that: WARNING: QGIS will crash if Qt4 developer components are installed in the standard /Developer location. Either rename /Developer/Applications/Qt/Plugins or uninstall Qt before running QGIS.

Comment: A reinstall didn't fix it, but fully removing QGIS and reinstalling did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue and removed QGIS by using free software "AppCleaner" from freemacsoft.net.

I then downloaded the last version from KingChaos (2.18.2-1) and installed step-by-step. Now, I have working QGIS!

I think, that the problem was with some plugins, that I had in old QGIS.

Comment: A couple re-installs didn't fix it, but merely dragging the QGIS.app into the trash and reinstalling the QGIS app worked for me.  No wonder Kyngchaos's 0_README file recommends trashing previous installs.

Answer (score 3):

try to find and remove (or rename) phonon.so in pyqt stuffs installed inside OSGeo4Mac installation. The crash happen only after OSX upgrade to 10.12.4. Phonon is a not well maintained multimedia package in QT. Probably the error is not present with QGIS master (e.g. python3/QT5)

this is the result of the investigation done in Boundless Spatial by Larry Shaffer, please let us know if it fix the problem.